# Is there a rule for manipulation of a matrix' eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say I have a matrix $A$ whose eigenvectors are set $U$. Is it possible to perform an "algorithm" on $A$ that produces a **similar** matrix $B$, whose eigenvectors are some specific set $V$ instead?

*Example*: if $A = \begin{pmatrix}2&1&0 \\ 0&2&0 \\ 0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$, its eigenvectors are the spans of $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$ and $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} \right\}$.

If I wanted a similar matrix whose eigenvectors are the spans of $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$ and $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} \right\}$, I could **guess** that $B = \begin{pmatrix}2&0&1\\0&2&0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$ is such a matrix. Is there an "algorithm" or a rule that could produce $B$?

Comment: There is a really useful property: you know that if $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$. So $\exists C \in Gl(n,\mathbb{K})$ : $D=C^{-1}AC$, where $C^{-1}$ is a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors ordered as your basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: This is indeed useful, but I have a more general case here - $A$ is non-diagonalizable, and therefore such a matrix $C$ is non-invertible ($C$ is the matrix with the desired eigenvectors as its columns), so I can't think of a a use for this property.

Comment: Eigenvectors are not a vector space, since $0$ is not an eigenvector.  Moreover, a sum of eigenvectors for different eigenvalues is never an eigenvector.  So even if you're willing to ignore the problem with $0$, what you're really talking about is the eigenspace for one eigenvalue.

Comment: Since you're right on both accounts, I will edit the question to be correct. Despite the terminology issue, I believe my question is still relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix having just one eigenvalue $\lambda$ with eigenspace $U$.  If $V$ is another subspace of $\mathbb C^n$ with the same dimension, then there is an invertible matrix $S$ with $U = SV$.  If $B = S^{-1} A S$, then for any $v \in V$, $Bv = S^{-1} A S v = \lambda v$; conversely, if $B x = \lambda x$, then $A S x = \lambda S x$ so $S x \in U$ and $x \in V$.  Thus $V$ is the eigenspace of $B$ for eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you! Could I try to generalize your answer for a case with multiple different eigenvalues?